# A conjecture about the positive continuous linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $A \colon \mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{X}$ be a continuous linear operator on a real ordered Banach space $\mathbb{X}$ with the positive cone $\mathbb{K}$.

It is well know from the **Neumann series** that if the operator norm $\| A\|$ of $A$ is strictly less than $1$,
i.e., $\| A\| <1$, then the liner operator equation 
$$ x = Ax +b \qquad (x \in \mathbb{X}, \,\, b \in \mathbb{K}),$$
has a unique solution, which is $x^*=(I-A)^{-1} b$.

> I am wondering that if the operator $A$ is additionally assumed to be positive 
>   (i.e., $A x \geq \theta$ whenever $x \geq \theta$, where $\theta$ is the zero 
>   element of $\mathbb{X}$), 
>   then could we conclude the following result
>   $$ x \geq x^* \implies x \geq Ax + b \,\,\,?$$

I was thinking to try to show that the linear operator $I-A$ is positive,
then we obtain $ x \geq x^* \implies (I-A)x \geq (I-A)x^*$ 
(since the positivity of a linear operator is identical to the
monotone increasing property),
in which case $(I-A)x \geq b$ yields the desired result $x \geq Ax +b$.
But I got stuck to showing the monotonicity of $I-A$. Besides, this might
not be a good approach.

In fact, if we let $\mathbb{X} = \mathbb{R}$,,
then the above linear operator equation becomes a linear equation 
with $A, b \in \mathbb{R}$,
and it is clear that the conjecture  $ x \geq x^* \implies x \geq Ax + b$ holds true.

Thus, I am curious that could we generalize such a result for an abstract Banach space?

*Any suggestion or idea are most welcome! Thank you very much!*

Comment: $(I-A)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n$ should allow you to prove $(1-A)$ is positive

Comment: Thanks @CalvinKhor . I tried to use the expression $(I- A)^{-1} = \sum^\infty_{n = 0} A^n$ to show the positivity of $(I-A)$, but this way did not lead to the desired result. Would you mind to explain this idea in a bit more detail please? How to utilize this expression to prove $(I-A)$ is positive? Many thanks :-)

Comment: well $A^n x \ge \theta$ for every $n$, Im not familiar with ordered Banach spaces but it feels like the limit should go through maybe with some lemma like $$ a_i \ge \theta \implies \sum a_i \ge \theta,$$so that $(I-A)^{-1}$ is positive, and then you should be able to get $(I-A)$ positive with $a\ge\theta, ab\ge\theta \implies b\ge\theta$. Is this too naive?

Comment: Apparently a cone need not be closed. Is yours closed? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065304/is-a-cone-in-banach-space-always-a-closed-subset

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you. I totally agree with you that the operator $(I-A)^{-1}$ is positive. But I did not see why the positivity of $(I-A)^{-1}$ could imply the positivity of $(I-A)$. Does such a fact that $a>\theta, ab>\theta \implies b>\theta$ apply to this case? Would you mind to explain this point please? Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks @CalvinKhor In this case, the positive cone $\mathbb{K}$ is closed. Maybe we can treat $\mathbb{X}$ to be the $L_p$ spaces.

Comment: Sorry, my inexperience with the subject is clear. I'll give it some more thought, thank you for introducing me to the subject

Comment: @CalvinKhor No worries at all :-) Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $X=\mathbb R^3$, $K$ to be the ice-cream cone
$$
K=\{x: \ x_3 \ge \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} \}.
$$
Define
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0.5}.
$$
Then for $x\in K$, $Ax\in K$. However, for every non-zero element of the boundary of $K$
it holds $(I-A)x\not\in K$, e.g., take 
$$
x=\pmatrix{0\\1\\1}, (I-A)x = \pmatrix{0\\1\\0.5}\not\in K.
$$

---

Here is also a $2d$ example: $X=\mathbb R^2$, $K=\{x: \ x_1\ge0,x_2\ge0\}$,
$$
A=\pmatrix{0.1&0.1\\0.1&0.1} ,\ 
x = \pmatrix{0\\1}, \ (I-A)x=\pmatrix{-0.1\\1.1}\not\in K.
$$

---

These examples also show that the implication
$$
x \ge (I-A)^{-1}b = x^* \ \Rightarrow\ (I-A)x \ge b
$$
is not true in general: simply take $b=x^*=0$ in the above examples.

Comment: Thank you very much @daw. It's really helpful :-)